# How to make Excel represent cell value as it is instead of formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large excel file (more 5000 records), and `some of the arbitrary cells show its value as a result returned from formula instead of the text value`. I can fix it by remove leading equal operator (this is the final result) but I can't manually line by line looking tirelessly through my excel file to detect all kind cells. Is there any solution? Thank you so much!

[image]

Updated:

I need something like that:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: If your intention is to convert the results of functions into their displayed results you should Copy the range and *Paste > Paste Special > Values* without changing the selection, meaning you paste to the same range from which you copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ribbon tab `Formulas` turn on `Show formulas` button and you will see all possible formulas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `FORMULATEXT()` function.

```
=FORMULATEXT(A2)
```

[image]

Comment: It's only addressed for this special case but not for normal case (E.g: 123456789 >> #N/A). Any simplifier solution? @Harun24HR